# How to enable write access to public in gitlab wiki

Tags: permissions, gitlab, wiki

I have created a Gitlab wiki. The repo is public, but noone is able to add or edit pages. How can I enable access write access for all visitors ?

Answer (score 0):

Under `Settings/General/Visibility,project features, permissions` make sure to check the Wiki permission levels, it can be **Only Project Members** or **Everyone with Access**
To enable access for all visitors select 'Everyone with access'

[image: Enable Wiki]

Comment: that*s my setup. But that's not what I want, because with this setup, all people which want add a page or edit one are needing a gitlab account and must request access to the wiki. Look at wikipedia. Account for editing is OK, but not request for access.